# How to fix white bodies on non-caucasian npc in fallout new vegas

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas

I recently started a new playthrough of Fallout New Vegas and decided to add a custom NPC. So I started up the G.E.C.K. and added a new NPC. I decided to make the NPC an AfricanAmerican. After doing some basic setup I placed the NPC somewere in Goodspring and test out what I had created so far (some basic dialog). However, the NPC turned up with a white body.

Since I ran a heavely modded game, including body replacers, I figured it might be a problem with Archive Invalidation, or one of the mods acting up.
So I removed all mods, tried again, but that didn't fix it.
I made sure I invalidated the archives (tried using FOMM, NMM, ArchiveInvalidatorValidated, manualy changing the INI's, etc.), but that did not work.
I then decided to do a complete clean reinstall of the game (making sure the to remove the game folder so all mods where deleted as well), but that didn't help either.

Note that I do not refer to the pale faces glitch which is fixed by a INI setting. Note also that I did all INI fixes in all three INI files.

So I'm unsure how to continue on fixing the game and would welcome any advice!

Comment: I don't have experience with the G.E.C.K., but is there any chance the character you created got glitched by the mods and saved the glitched body? It'd explain why it still shows like that after you removed the mods.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It could be possible, but after reinstalling the game and making sure the mods where deleted and removing all save games, the problem still exists, even when starting creating a new mod.